# C# changing the layout of the form with a button

Tags: c#, layout

Ok, I am a 1st year computer engineer, I am new to C#, and I have a project on chemistry where we will create a periodic table application. Problem is how do I sort pictures in C#, example, With one click it would only show all Alkaline Metals and all Non-Alkaline Metals will be gone.

I  tried creating forms with already sorted elements and with one click of a button, lets say "Alkaline Metal", the Alkaline metal form will be shown and the old form will be hidden. But I think its ugly and confusing.

So my plan is to just change the layout of the form with one click, but how do I do that ?

Comment: Well. As a human how would you do it? How are you storing those pictures internally? what data structures and code do you think you might need?

Comment: What technology is this app in? Windows forms, WPF, Webforms, MVC etc?

Comment: Can you show one of these: 1) A picture of what you are trying to achieve 2) Some code

Comment: @Mant101 Windows Form

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Answer (score 0):

If I was you I would do something so simple, I would create the periodic table using all picture boxes.

Next I would add a boolean value to each of the picture boxes, like you said whether is is an Alkaline Metal etc.

I'm not sure if you have done Arrays yet but this would be the easiest way to do it just have each bool in the array match up to each picture box on your form.

So to filter them out you would just press a button and then go through the array of bools, if you see one that is set to an Alkaline Metal you would leave that picturebox.Visible = enabled and if its not one then change the picturebox.Visible = false.

I really think as a low level first year design this would be the best thing you could do, I don't know any of your experience but I wouldn't go creating multiple forms I would simply hide the pictureboxes you dont want to see with the above commands.

Best of luck and let me know how you get on.

Answer (score 0):

You can change some of the properties of the forms (e.g. Width, Height) when a certain event occurs (click a button). Meaning you can change the size of the form as a result of a button click. In addition you can have multiple containers (groupbox, picturebox, etc..) in the form but with visible property set to false and when the button is clicked change it to true

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert, but like some already pointed out, best approach would be to have each element as a pic inside a form, group them in a array, for example alkalineMetals [] = {picMetal1, picMetal2, etc};
Then if user selects non alkaline metals for example, you can set the pic property visible to false:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Visible = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the table look like a [real periodic table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_table#Periodic_table_legend_for_category) you will need not just the data and/or images you want to display.

You also need to store the placement rules for each.

For the basic table these would simply be the row & column numbers; but for the more flexible display you want to create you would also need a little more, say a group-id, best as an enumerable.

To display them you could use a `DataGridView` or a `TableLayoutPanel`.

When switching the display you would clear the container and start filling in all element that belong to the groups you want to display at their given coordinates.

You should collect the images in an `ImageList` and create `Labels` by assigning their `BackGroundImages` to image from the `ImageList`.

Will you need to follow extra rules about the placement when switching the display? There are some, as far as I remember my chemistry..

So you should start by creating a `class Element` and give it some properties like int `Row` and `Column` and `imageIndex` and `groupID`; then the `enum ElementGroups { AlkalineMetals, NonAlkalineMetals..  };`

Then define the layout with the necessary `Checkboxes` for the groups to display or hide. Finally the container, say a `TableLayoutPanel`, large enough to hold all elements..

Another thing to decide is whether you really want to use pictures or would rather create the element display dynamically from data. It usually involved nothing more that 2-4 strings to print and a back color. Not rocketscience to draw this..

Have you already gotten the [data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_element)?

Comment: I am planning to use a picture box to display the elements one by one, and when the picture box is pressed, it will display the elements on another form using a picture box again, with all the information.  I also have simple knowledge on Photoshop so that would be easy. All I need is how to sort them. Thanks for your answer btw.

Comment: A PictureBox as such can only display one Image. So to display a number of elements you would either have to use several PictureBoxes or paint each element's image onto one large PictureBox surface. For the 1st way you would place the PBs at the right spots in the container, maybe the Form; for the 2nd way you would draw the images in the paint event at the right coordinates using a DrawImage call for each. Both can be done dynamically.

Comment: - For both cases you need to know something about the layout. For this drawing them all in Photoshop will not do. You need to attach their coordinates to the images. Either by, say, naming them in some clever way, or, much better imo, by creating a call Element with all the data you need, including, maybe, a filename. But as I said, if you have the data (Atomic number & weight, Name, Symbol) drawing them with four DrawString calls is pretty simple. If you add Group and Period to the data and element type you should be able to use them for calculating the coodinates and a Color..